# Xpaths, return a ref field based on values of its children

Tags: xml, xpath

Example:

```
 <Products>
            <Product ref="apple">
                <Type>FRUIT</Type>
                <Price>100</Price>                
            </Product>
            <Product ref="cabbage">
                <Type>VEGETABLE</Type>
                <Price>200</Price>                
            </Product>
</Products>
```

What is a valid xpaths expression that would give me the value(s) of the ref(s) of all type=VEGETABLE ? In this case, it'll return cabbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this specific XPath-1.0 expression

```
/Products/Product[Type='VEGETABLE']/@ref
```

or this more generic one

```
//Product[Type='VEGETABLE']/@ref
```

Comment: What if I want to match the attribute of <Type> ?

Comment: `<Type>` has no attribute, so I don't know what you refer to.